# Combine picture and text in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to output **text** + image + **text** in HAML. I know that I can do

```
=image_tag('some.png') + "text"
```

to have the text immediately after the picture. But how can I prepend some text?

```
="text" + image_tag('some.png') + "text"
```

does not work. What I get is

```
text
<img alt="" src="some.png" />text
```

which renders a blank between the first text and the image. I would rather like to have

```
text<img alt="" src="some.png" />text
```

My 2nd attempt above renders

```
text&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;some.png&quot; /&gt;text
```

Comment: What do you mean by “does not work”? What HTML do you want to generate, and what are you getting?

Comment: `="text" + image_tag('some.png') + "text"` generates `text<img src="/images/some.png" alt="Some" />text` for me.

Comment: @matt Hmm. Maybe I just need some update?

Comment: @matt Strange. I just updated but still the same result. Anyhow, the solution below works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
view file:

```
%span
  = "text".html_safe
  = image_tag('/apple-icon-57x57.png')
  = "text"
```

css file:

```
span img { display: inline; }
```

Comment: Well, that puts image and text together. But the whole thing now is enclosed in a `div` which renders a new paragraph.

Comment: It looks like the css addition is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a solution was to render a new image with the texts and the image together. This way they always appear joined.